# Is there any way to implement pagination in spring webflux and spring data reactive

Tags: spring, mongodb, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux

I'm trying to understand reactive part of spring 5. I have created simple rest endpoint for finding all entities using spring `web-flux` and spring data reactive (mongo) but don't see any way how to implement pagination.

Here is my simple example in Kotlin:

```
@GetMapping("/posts/")
fun getAllPosts() = postRepository.findAll()
```

**Does it mean that reactive endpoint does not require pagination?** Is some way to implement pagination from server side using this stack?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Custom Query with pageable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296533/spring-custom-query-with-pageable)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reactive support in Spring Data does not provide means of a `Page` return type. Still, the `Pageable` parameter is supported in method signatures passing on `limit` and `offset` to the drivers and therefore the store itself, returning a `Flux<T>` that emits the range requested.

```java
Flux<Person> findByFirstname(String firstname, Pageable pageable);
```

For more information please have a look at the current [Reference Documentation for 2.0.RC2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/html/#mongo.reactive.repositories.usage) and the [Spring Data Examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/mongodb/reactive).

Comment: btw this is not working for Reactive Spring Data Repositories.

Answer (score 7):

**Flux** provides `skip` and `take` methods to get pagination support, <del>and you also can use `filter` and `sort` to filter and sort the result.</del> **The filter and sort below is not a good example, but use `skip` and `Pageable` as 2nd parameter are no different.**

The following codes work for me.

```
@GetMapping("")
public Flux<Post> all(
//@RequestParam(value = "q", required = false) String q,
                      @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") long page,
                      @RequestParam(value = "size", defaultValue = "10") long size) {
    return this.postRepository.findAll()
        //.filter(p -> Optional.ofNullable(q).map(key -> p.getTitle().contains(key) || p.getContent().contains(key)).orElse(true))//(replace this with query parameters)
        .sort(comparing(Post::getCreatedDate).reversed())
        .skip(page * size).take(size);
}
```

**Update**: The underlay drivers should be responsible for handling the result in the **reactivestreams** way.

And as you see in the answer from Christoph, if using a `findByXXX` method, Spring Data Mongo Reactive provides a variant to accept a `pageable` argument, but the `findAll`(reactive version) **does not include such a variant**, you have to do `skip` in the later operations if you really need the **pagination** feature. When switching to `Flux` instead of List, imagine the data in Flux as living water in the rivers or oil in the pipes, or the tweets in twitter.com.

I have tried to compare the queries using `Pageale` and not in the following case.

```java
this.postRepository.findByTitleContains("title")
                .skip(0)
                .limitRequest(10)
                .sort((o1, o2) -> o1.getTitle().compareTo(o2.getTitle()))


this.postRepository.findByTitleContains("title", PageRequest.of(0, 10, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "title")))
```

When enabling logging for `logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate=DEBUG` and found they print the same log for queries.

```sh
 find using query: { "title" : { "$regularExpression" : { "pattern" : ".*title.*", "options" : ""}}} fields: Document{{title=1}} for class: class com.example.demo.Post in collection: post

//other logging...

 find using query: { "title" : { "$regularExpression" : { "pattern" : ".*title.*", "options" : ""}}} fields: Document{{title=1}} for class: class com.example.demo.Post in collection: post
```

**Keep in mind, all these operations should be DELEGATED to the underlay R2dbc drivers which implemented the reactive streams spec and performed on the DB side, NOT in the memory of your application side**.

Check the [example codes](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/boot-data-mongo/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostRepositoryPageableTest.java).

*The early sample code I provided above maybe is not a good sample of `filter` and `sort` operations(MongoDB itself provides great `regularexpression` operations for it). But pagination in the reactive variant is not a good match with the concept in the reactive stream spec. When embracing Spring reactive stack, most of the time, we just move our work to a new collection of APIs. In my opinion, the realtime update and elastic response scene could be better match **Reactive**, eg. using it with SSE, Websocket, RSocket, `application/stream+json`(missing in the new Spring docs) protocols, etc*

Comment: Won't this consume more resources (mem and CPU) than `Mono<Page<T>>`?

Comment: This would be really inefficient on large collections with thousands+ documents. It's better to do the filtering on DB side then load all records and filter them in code.

Comment: @Mavo I do not think there is a performance problem if the db driver fully implements ReactiveStrreams, it should delegate these operations to underlay db directly.

Comment: I've tested both options, Flux filtering is MUCH slower than running the query properly on MongoDB.

Comment: @OCPi I think you are right, the operation could iterate the result one by one and return what you want on the DB side. I think it is a little like returning a Stream result in JPA, where it will use JDBC cursor to iterate in data in DB. It should **never** load all data in memory and filter them.

Comment: It should be slower because Flux is from a Java library and you need to serialize and deserialize data from the database. You don't need to serialize 1M rows if you finally need two of them.

Comment: @Zon It depends on the db drivers, at the moment, most of the database, including SQL database and noSQL provide ReactiveStreams compatible drivers. I do not think it is need to do some serialization and deserialization in all data in the stream.

Comment: @Hantsy I was under the same impression as well, but that's not the case. When you have a Flux of data coming from DB, that DB (tested with reactive Cassandra) still needs to fetch all records and then start streaming. Now later in the code if you choose to filter/skip some records, you still have those many records pulled from DB and hence would be slower. Hence using Pageable object in the Spring Data query itself will be faster.

Comment: @SanjayRawat That is the problem of the reactive driver. I do not think it is reactive streams compatible, if it is working as you describe, the reactive implementation in Cassandra is meaningless, why stick on it,  switching to the traditional blocking will simplifying the work. I have tried the Spring Data Mongo Reactive, worked well.  As I said the `Pageable` was only  allowed to apply to the method with a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not efficient but it works for me while I look for another solution**

**Service**

```
public Page<Level> getPage(int page, int size, Sort.Direction direction, String properties) {
    var pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, size, direction, properties);
    var count = levelRepository.count().block();
    var levels = levelRepository.findAllLevelsPaged(pageRequest).collectList().block();
    return new PageImpl<>(Objects.requireNonNull(levels), pageRequest, Objects.requireNonNull(count));
}
```

**Repo**

```
@Repository
public interface LevelRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Level, String> {

    @Query("{ id: { $exists: true }}")
    Flux<Level> findAllLevelsPaged(final Pageable page);

}
```

**Ref [example](https://newbedev.com/how-apply-pagination-in-reactive-spring-data)**