# R2dbcRepository BeanCreationException No property findAll found for type

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I try to update the whole application and use the reactive programming approach with PostgreSQL, so I'm updating the repositories and make them extend from R2dbcRepository, updated also related services to handle Mono and Flux.
When I try to run the application I have an exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'temperatureLibraryReactiveRepository'
defined in com.PlayGroundAdv.Solar.repositories.reactive.TemperatureLibraryReactiveRepository defined
in @EnableR2dbcRepositories declared on SolarApplication: Invocation of init method failed
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method 
public abstract reactor.core.publisher.Flux
com.PlayGroundAdv.Solar.repositories.reactive.TemperatureLibraryReactiveRepository.findAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! 
No property findAll found for type TemperatureLibraryEntity!
```

I'm not sure if this is due to the usage of `Pageable`, and if it's the case I did not find any alternative for `Pageable` with the R2DBC approach.

everything used to work fine with the JPA approach
here's my repository

```
import com.PlayGroundAdv.Solar.entity.TemperatureLibraryEntity;
import com.PlayGroundAdv.Solar.model.AllPostalCodeModel;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.R2dbcRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Repository
public interface TemperatureLibraryReactiveRepository extends R2dbcRepository<TemperatureLibraryEntity, Long> {

    // A.B 11-18 Get All Temp By postal Code
    Flux<TemperatureLibraryEntity> findByPostalCode(String postalCode, Pageable pageable);

    String FIND_POSTAL_CODE = "SELECT new com.PlayGroundAdv.Solar.model.AllPostalCodeModel ( u.id, u.postalCode) FROM TemperatureLibraryEntity u order by u.postalCode";

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = FIND_POSTAL_CODE)
    Flux<AllPostalCodeModel> findAllPostalCode();
    Flux<TemperatureLibraryEntity> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `@repository` annotation, set `basePackages` to the packages which contain the repositories in the `EnableR2dbcRepositories`.
2. For pagination, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924505/is-there-any-way-to-implement-pagination-in-spring-webflux-and-spring-data-react/48078520#48078520). There is no `PaginationAndSortRepository` for the reactive case now.

Check the sample about R2dbc from [my reactive sample repository](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample).

And [the sample for the lastest Spring 5.3 and Spring Data R2dbc 1.2](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample), there is [an example for pagination](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/boot/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java#L343). Some breaking changes are introduced in this version, I will update the sample codes next week when the next milestone(Spring Data R2dbc 1.2.0-RC1) is released which includes some bugfixes.