# Does applying Pagination on response using Spring Webflux make it blocking?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Does the following code block the call, if so how do I make it non-blocking? i.e. making the use of Reactive Java Stream useless? How can I paginate without making the call blocking?

Currently I have a webClient calling to a backend service that returns a `Flux<Item>` and according to specs I need to return a `ResponseEntity<ItemListResponse>` where I have provide a paginated response

code inside the controller method looks like ->

```
// getItems method was initially returning a Flux but my method was failing to paginate it so now that method returns a Mono<List<Item>>
// I would really like to see how I can make this work with Flux!
return webClient.getItems(...required params...)
           .map(r -> {
              // we get offset and limit from query params
              var paginatedItems = listPaginator.applyPagination(r, offset, limit)
              // assembleItemResponse method maps all values from backend service to new response required by client
              List<ItemResponse> itemResponseList = paginatedItems.stream()
                       .map(this::assembleItemResponse)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());

              return ResponseEntity.ok()
                         .body(ItemListResponse.builder()
                                 .itemCount(r.size())
                                 .pagesize(itemResponseList.size())
                                 .listItems(itemResponseList)
                                 .build());
              });
```

Comment: Are you using MogoDB? if yes you can use Reactive Tailable Cursors (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-tailable-cursors).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to implement pagination in spring webflux and spring data reactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924505/is-there-any-way-to-implement-pagination-in-spring-webflux-and-spring-data-react)

Comment: No, that does not answer my question, I am just using a backend service (not Mongo). So I am not using Spring Data. It partially provide me info on skip() and take() methods. My question is the above code blocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does applying Pagination on response using Spring Webflux make it blocking?

There's nothing *inherently* blocking about pagination, but the normal Spring Data way to achieve that is by using a `PagingAndSortingRepository` to query the data layer for only the results you need for that particular page (as oppose to querying the data layer for all possible results then filtering, which could have a huge performance impact depending on the data size.) Unfortunately that approach *is* blocking. The `PagingAndSortingRepository` doesn't as of yet have a reactive equivalent.

However, that doesn't appear to be what you're doing here. A complete example here would be helpful, but it looks like `r` is a list of items, and then you're applying a listPaginator to that entire list to reduce it down. If that's the case then there's no reason why it would *necessarily* be blocking, so it should be safe. However, it's impossible to say for certain without knowing the specific behaviour of the `applyPagination` and `assembleItemResponse` methods. If those methods are blocking then no - you're not safe here, and you need to consider another approach (exactly what approach would require a more complete example.) If those methods are non-blocking (they just deal with the data they have, don't call any further web / db services, etc.) then you're ok.

Separately, you might consider looking at [Blockhound](https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound) which will be able to tell you for certain whether you have any blocking calls where they shouldn't be.

Comment: Thank you! that makes a lot of sense. I will update the questions with code for applyPagination and assembleItemResponse methods.
from what I can see is they are not blocking.(I may be incorrect about applyPagination). I saw the code for using the `PagingAndSortingRepository` but I am making a call to a backend service not a database. 
The service doesn't provide pagination.
`r` is Mono<List<Items>>, instead of that I want to have Flux<Item> return from the but I had to use the mono because I thought I won't be able to paginated the response because I don't have the whole List of items.