# Keyset(Seek) Pagination in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pagination, spring-data-mongodb

Currently I'm trying to implement keyset, aka. seek pagination for Spring Data MongoDB. Currently I'm trying to go about this by using the information provided [here](https://www.codementor.io/@arpitbhayani/fast-and-efficient-pagination-in-mongodb-9095flbqr). Unfortunately, this is a low-level implementation, and I was hoping to get some sort of abstraction similar to [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/seek-clause/), as they don't seem to support MongoDB.

Is there any abstractions/easy ways out there that would allow me to accomplish this task, or is this something I would need to implement on a low-level on my own?

Comment: Does the below answer solved your problem?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using spring data MongoDb then you could easily achieve it through **[MongoDB repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html)**

For example, accessing the second page of User by a page size of 20 you could simply do something like this:

> PagingAndSortingRepository repository = // … get access to a bean
>
> Page users = repository.findAll(new PageRequest(1, 20));

For more details, please go through the below official documentation:

1. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html
2. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html
3. [Spring Custom Query with pageable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296533/spring-custom-query-with-pageable)

Hope these documentation solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the technique used by PagingAndSortingRepository for pagination is offset pagination, not keyset pagination. I haven't really been able to find any quick and easy solutions that implement keyset pagination "for free". Thanks for the attempt however, I appreciate it.