# Keyset(Seek) Pagination and MongoDb Driver C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to paginate my MongoDB results by means of keyset/seek pagination using the C# MongoDB Driver. I am NOT trying to use offset pagination.

Essentially, I have a database containing *many* `tags`. The structure of a `tag` is as follows:

```json
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fc5cdb5d6ee08681d32d3ba"),
        "UsageCount" : NumberLong(123456),
        "Name" : "technology"
}
```

I want to fist *sort* my database in descending order by the `UsageCount` property. This property is not unique. Many `tags` can have the same value for `UsageCount`. Example results would be:

```json
[
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5fc5cdb5d6ee08681d32d3ba"),
                "UsageCount" : NumberLong(9000),
                "Name" : "technology"
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5fc5cdb5d6ee08681d32d3b1"),
                "UsageCount" : NumberLong(8000),
                "Name" : "technology"
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5fc5cdb5d6ee08681d32d3b2"),
                "UsageCount" : NumberLong(7000),
                "Name" : "technology"
        },
        ...
]
```

Example C# code:

```cs
// Get the mongo queryable
IMongoQueryable<Tag> tags = _mongoDbService.GetCollection<Tag>(nameof(Tag));

// Order the database descending by usage count
IOrderedMongoQueryable<Tag> orderedTags = tags.OrderByDescending(tag => tag.UsageCount);

// Take the tag after the tag with ID 5fc5cdb5d6ee08681d32d3b1
List<Tag> results = orderedTags.After("5fc5cdb5d6ee08681d32d3b1").Take(1).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The results of this code should be a list containing only the last tag from the example above:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc5cdb5d6ee08681d32d3b2"),
    "UsageCount" : NumberLong(7000),
    "Name" : "technology"
}
```

**The problem here is that the `After` method in the above code doesn't exist. I am looking to accomplish the same result be any means available.**

Some possible solutions might be to

1. First find the *index* of `5fc5cdb5d6ee08681d32d3b2` in the sorted document list and then call `skip(index)`. This requires two queries, which isn't quite as nice but more importantly, I don't know if I can find the index either?
2. Find a method equivalent to `After`?
3. Others?

I have seen this question asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59396901/keysetseek-pagination-in-spring-data-mongodb) with no solutions.

Answer (score 2):

you can get the desired result using an aggregation pipeline like this:

```java
db.Tags.aggregate(
[
    {
        $sort: { UsageCount: -1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            tags: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            tags: {
                $slice: [
                    "$tags",
                    { $add: [{ $indexOfArray: ["$tags._id", ObjectId("5fc5cdb5d6ee08681d32d3b1")] }, 1] },
                    { $size: "$tags" }]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$tags"
    },
    {
        $replaceWith: "$tags"
    }
]
)
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/uqmxl7cBCMA

however, it will be quite difficult (if not impossible) to translate this into a strongly-typed c# query. have a look at this [library](https://mongodb-entities.com/wiki/String-Templates.html) for an alternative way to run complex queries like the above.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the efficiency of this query as well as an explanation of the steps and how it works? I consider myself a mongo novice and would very much appreciate being able to lean more about what exactly is going on here.

Comment: i'll add an explanation as soon as i get some free time. in the meantime visit the mongo docs site and look at each of the `$xxxx` operators used in the pipeline. should give you an idea what each operator does. as for the efficiency, it should work relatively fast for a couple of million tags at least if you have an index on the `UsageCount` field. you'll have to run tests on your dataset to find out how exactly it performs though.